# is there any option to execute hql query with procedure?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have query in SQL like

```
 select part_no, base_price, fn_get_ecom_item_new_price(Company_id, Part_No, Unit, Price, 'N') newPrice  from ecom_prodmast
```

if there is an option to run the same query in hibernate?  there is any other way to execute a select query with function in hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session.get() method from Hibernate and the generated Java classes, then will look something like that:

```
SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
Session session=factory.openSession();  
Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  
Economy e= (Economy) session.get(Economy.class, part_no ....);
t.commit();
session.close();  
return e.getData();
```

The main Economy class should be configured to hold your data like part_no, base_price, fn_get_ecom_item_new_price, etc. of your ecom_prodmast table. That means first configure Hibernate and generate the classes, then use them. You can find examples on the internet on how to.
If you are using Eclipse is even simpler, because it exists a plug-in that does that for you.
If you want to access the procedure, that should also exist in the generated files and you call it as a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
use a native query.

Here is a link to [Chapter 16. Native SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html).

For more information,
try a google search for "hibernate stored procedures mysql",
there are about a million hits.